# Moving some rows from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move some rows from worksheet1 to worksheet2 provided that I have input some completion date on the blank cell. I got code from somebody but it is not quite my requirement.  I need to change the word "DONE" with some date. i.e.: 1-Jun, if the cell is not dated then no need to move to another worksheet2
code as follows:

```
Sub Ed()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1:L" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Done" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Done" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you determine what "Some date" is supposed to be? Have you tried just changing "Done" to "2020-01-01"?

Comment: you need to change "DONE" to a date. OK. So, what's your question?